# ¿Cómo transferir la propiedad de un archivo automáticamente?

Tags: python, google-drive, google-oauth, g-suite

Un cliente me ha solicitado que le desarrollo un script para cambiar automáticamente el propietario de los archivos contenidos en una carpeta.
Dado que GAS no permite el cambio de propietarios a los ficheros de otros usuarios he intentado hacerlo con "Delegating domain-wide authority to the service account" de la guía[https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount]
Usando el siguiente código:

```py
def main():
    credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)
    delegated_credentials = credentials.with_subject('google-drive@bitnami-c0ooayu.iam.gserviceaccount.com')
    service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=delegated_credentials)
    files = service.files().list().execute()
    file_list = [each.get('id') for each in files.get('files')]
    for file_id in file_list:
        per =  service.permissions().list(fileId=file_id).execute()
        edit_id = ''
        for each in per['permissions']:
            if each.get('role') == 'writer':
                 edit_id = each.get('id')
        permission = service.permissions().update(
             fileId=file_id, permissionId=edit_id, transferOwnership='true', 
             body={'role': 'owner'}).execute()
```

Resultado:

googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/1YEHKl4c-EeHEaMdcWDa9YhSZFXYDxFDZ/permissions/15874118146408716
691?alt=json&transferOwnership=true returned "The user does not have sufficient permissions for this file.">

¿Alguna sugerencia?
Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Te he dejado una respuesta general. Sería bueno que indicaras el tipo de cuenta de tu cliente (si es de gmail.com o de G Suite), el formato de los archivos y si estos son del mismo dominio o de otro dominio.

Answer (score 0):

Usando cuentas de usuario regular sólo se pueden cambiar el propietario de los archivos de los editores de Google (Documentos, Hojas de Cálculo, Presentaciones, Dibujos, Scripts) pero no archivos "cargados" (PDF, DOCX, PNG, MP3, etc,)

En el caso de archivos de los editores de Google, usando cuentas regulares sólo el propietario, ya sea de forma manual o mediante un script, sólo propietario puede hacer el cambio de propietario.

Usando cuentas de G Suite y "[domain-wide authority delegation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#delegatingauthority)" (¿"delegación de autoridad a nivel dominio" ?) es posible hacer el cambio de propietario de un usuario a otro usuario del dominio pero no es posible de un usuario de un dominio ajeno a otro usuario del propio dominio ni viceversa.

Una alternativa es hacer copias de los archivos de los que no se es propietario.

Comment: Gracias por su respuesta Rubén y perdone usted si no fuí lo suficientemente explicativo.. Las cuentas son todas del mismo dominio de Gsuite y el propietario de la carpeta es superadmin en el dominio.. Los archivos son todos los nativos de google(Documentos, Hojas de Cálculo, Presentaciones).. Manualmente el superadmin puede cambiar todos los ficheros de propietario, pero el script no es capas de hacerlo..

Comment: @YuneskyDelRío Por favor agrega los detalles relevantes a la pregunta

Comment: El tipo de objeto del service(service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=delegated_credentials)) es: "googleapiclient.discovery.Resource"

Comment: @YuneskyDelRío : Lo que compartes que has intentado es relevante. Como solicité en mi comentario previo, agrega los detalles relevantes a la pregunta en parte porque ahí podrás darle un mejor formato al código y así facilitar su lectura.